# Microsoft SQL Server management STUDIO VS Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I log into SQL Server Management Studio with an Admin account, I can see all the databases in the navigation pane. Double clicking on each one, will expand the DB and I can see DB specific objects such as tables.

With Oracle and SQL developer tool, you connect to a specific database and you only see that DB. You can expand it and see the schemas inside it.

My question is, is there a way to log into oracle SQL developer as an admin and view all the databases in the navigation pane, just like SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: What do you mean by "database"? Oracle and SQL Server use different terminology and with SQL Developer you would connect as a database user to a database instance and you would see the tables owned by that user and, [in SQL Developer](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/03/why-cant-i-see-my-tables-in-oracle-sql-developer/), there is an "Other Users" expandable item in the list where you can see tables that the user you have connected as has the permissions to view.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes close is if you're using a multitenated architecture instances of Oracle, where you have one container database with one or more pluggable databases.

You can see and manage these in the DBA Panel.

[image]

But SQLDev isn't like SSMS where you can navigate databases via a single connection. You would create connections for each PDB you want to work with on a regular basis.